# select array value based on cycle number

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array and I need to select a value from array depending upon the cycle number. It follows a pattern. For cycle 1, the constants are defined as per array index. If cycle is increased by "1", then constants will have the values of array by moving the array index by 1. I did the following and I do not know how to simplify the code. Pls help!!

```
var cycle = 1
let myStr: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]

if cycle == 1{
let a = myStr[0]; let b = myStr[1]; let c = myStr[2]; let d = myStr[3]; let e=myStr[4]; let f = myStr[5]; let g = myStr[6]; let h = myStr[7]; let i = myStr[8]
}else if cycle == 2{
  let a = myStr[8]; let b = myStr[0]; .... let i = myStr[7]
}else if cycle == 3{
  let a = myStr[7]; let b = myStr[8]; ....  let i = myStr[6]
}else if cycle == 4{
  let a = myStr[6]; let b = myStr[7]; .... let i = myStr[5]
}else if cycle == 5{
  let a = myStr[5]; let b = myStr[6]; .... let i = myStr[4]
}else if cycle == 6{
  let a = myStr[4]; let b = myStr[5]; .... let i = myStr[3]
}else if cycle == 7{
  let a = myStr[3]; let b = myStr[4]; ....  let i = myStr[2]
}else if cycle == 8{
  let a = myStr[2]; let b = myStr[3]; ....  let i = myStr[1]
}else if cycle == 9{
  let a = myStr[1]; let b = myStr[2]; .... let i = myStr[0]
}
```

In the button action, i have the following

```
    cycle = cycle + 1
    if cycle > 9{
        cycle = 1
    }
```

Comment: yes, but still i will have to code all the constants for switch case. Is there anyway i can code the index of array, such that i reduce the number of lines of code

Comment: @MK4 See the question i linked. I think it does exactly what you're looking for

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks!!